# CSqlDataProvider sort attributes in CListView

Tags: php, yii

I have the following, a $dataprovider in Controller:

```
$sql = 'select * from tbl_user order by id_user';
$count = 'select count(*) from tbl_user';

$dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
  'keyField' => 'id_user',
  'totalItemCount' => $count,
  'sort' => array(
    'attributes' => array(
      'name',
    ),
  ),
  'pagination' => array(
    'pageSize' => 15,
  ),
));
```

and ClistView in view:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,   
  'sortableAttributes' => array(
   'name' => 'Name',     
  ),   
));
```

The Sort by: Name appears but when i click nothing happens i.e. the ajax request works but my records are not sorted. What am i missing? Thanks.

I have solved the problem with:

```
$sql = 'select * from tbl_user';

$dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
  'keyField' => 'id_user',
  'totalItemCount' => $count,
  'sort' => array(
    'attributes' => array(
      'name',
    ),
  'defaultOrder' => array('name' => false)
  ),
  'pagination' => array(
    'pageSize' => 15,
  ),
));
```

The idea is to remove any order by from within the sql statement and let the csqldataprovider to handle it.

Comment: show the url of ajax-request when you click on the column name

Comment: index?ajax=id_of_clistview&sort=name.desc